# Dynamically show intersection of two functions inside Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

I want to add some kind of arrows (or some kind of function) on the x-axis (as depicted). if sin(x) is higher than b*x, then arrow should point to the right, in the interval between its two intersection. A left arrow, if b*x is higher than sin(x). Arrows should vary with change of paramters.

[image: adding arrows]

```
func[x_, b_] := b*x;
Manipulate[
 Plot[{a*Sin[x], func[x, b]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}],
 {a, 1, 10}, {b, 0.5, 10}]
```

Comment: Can you be more clear as to what you mean when `Sin[x]` greater than `bx`? For `a=1` and `b=0.5`, at $x=1$ `Sin[x]>bx` at $x=4$ `Sin[x]<bx`. At the intersection `Sin[x]==bx`. At which point of `x` are you evaluating at?

Comment: if i lower b or raise a, then the interval where sin[x] is greater than bx gets larger. Then the left arrow pointing to the right should get longer aswell (until sin[x] is lower than bx).
There is no specific point of x where i am evaluating at. The arrow should vary with the parameters a and b.

Answer (score 6):

**Update 2:** Dealing with question in the comments:

*My original code is much longer and with multiple functions. I don't use the command `Show` in it. So if i add `/. Line->Arrow` all functions get an arrow. Is there a possibility to use `/. Line ->Arrow` separately on functions?*

You can put the `/. Line->Arrow` piece after `Plot[...]`, and specify `Arrowheads[0]` for the lines that you want to be rendered as `Line`s as part of the `PlotStyle` setting. For example:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{a*Sin[x], func[x, b], 
     ConditionalExpression[0, func[x, b] <= a Sin[x]], 
     ConditionalExpression[0, func[x, b] >= a Sin[x]]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Arrowheads[0], ColorData[54, "ColorList"][[1]]], 
      Directive[Thick, Arrowheads[0], ColorData[54, "ColorList"][[2]]], 
      Directive[Red, Thick, Arrowheads[{0, .05}]], 
      Directive[Blue, Thick, Arrowheads[{-.05, 0}]]}] /. Line -> Arrow,
   {a, 1, 10}, {b, 0.5, 10}]
```

[image]

Note: In version 9, you don't have to use `/. Line->Arrow` trick. You can use functions to specify the `PlotStyle` and use  `({Directive[Blue, Thick, Arrowheads[{-.05, 0}], Arrow@@#}&) in place of`Directive[Blue, Thick, Arrowheads[{-.05, 0}]`. But this method no longer works in newer versions.

**Update:** If you have Version 10 or newer versions, you can also use `NumberLinePlot` as `Epilog`:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{a*Sin[x], func[x, b]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    Epilog -> First[NumberLinePlot[{a Sin[x] <= func[x, b], 
       a Sin[x] > func[x, b]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
      PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick, Arrowheads[{-.05, 0}]], 
         Directive[Blue, Thick, Arrowheads[{0, .05}]]}, 
      Spacings -> 0] /. Line -> Arrow]],
   {a, 1, 10}, {b, 0.5, 10}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
Manipulate[Show[Plot[{a*Sin[x], func[x, b]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}], 
  Plot[{ConditionalExpression[0, func[x, b] <= a Sin[x]], 
        ConditionalExpression[0, func[x, b] >= a Sin[x]]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick, Arrowheads[{0, .05}]], 
      Directive[Blue, Thick, Arrowheads[{-.05, 0}]]}] /. Line -> Arrow], 
 {a, 1, 10}, {b, 0.5, 10}]
```

[image]

You can also use a combination of `Epilog` and `ParametricPlot` with `Mesh` options:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{a*Sin[x], func[x, b]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Epilog -> First[ParametricPlot[{x, 0}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
      MeshFunctions -> {a Sin[#] - func[#, b] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
      MeshShading -> {Directive[Red, Thick, Arrowheads[{-.05, 0}]], 
        Directive[Blue, Thick, Arrowheads[{0, .05}]]}] /. Line -> Arrow]], 
  {a, 1, 10}, {b, 0.5, 10}]
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit of how the `ConditionalExpression[]` is working? It returns `0` when `func[x,b]<=a Sin[x]` and `0` when `func[x,b]>=a Sin[x]`. Since the 2nd argument to `ConditionalExpression[]` is the cond., I can't seem to be able to wrap my head around how you are getting the coordinates.

Comment: @IshouldchangemyUsername, `ConditionalExpression[0,condition]` gives 0 if the `condition` is satisfied and Nothing otherwise. The `Nothing` portion is not plotted so we get, in the current case, a line from `{0,0}` to  `{0,x*}` where `x*` is the maximum point where condition is satisfied. BTW, `ConditionalExpression[0,condition]` gives the same result as `Piecewise[{{0,condition}}, Nothing]` (which may be more intuitive). Hope this helps.

Comment: `ConditionalExpression[0, func[x, b] <= a Sin[x]` is a condition where i only compare two functions with each other. What if i need to compare `func[x,b]` with two functions (for example with asin(x) and acos(x)?  `ConditionalExpression[0, func[x, b] <= {a Sin[x], a Cos[x]}`  does not work

Comment: @Manuel, `condition` in `ConditionalExpression[0,condition]` should be a Boolean function that evaluates to `True` or `False`. So, you can use `And @@ Thread[func[x, b] <= {a Sin[x], a Cos[x]}]` or `Or @@ Thread[func[x, b] <= {a Sin[x], a Cos[x]}]` as `condition` in `ConditionalExpression[0,condition]`

Comment: if i add `/. Line -> Arrow` after my closing Plot Bracket ] , all my function get an arrow. Where do i add  `/. Line -> Arrow` and do i need the command `Show[]` for it?

Comment: @ManuelFülling, if you are using the `Epilog` version, you need to use `/. Line->Arrow` after the plot inside  `First[...]`.

Comment: i am using your version with `ConditionalExpression`

Comment: @Manuel, then it should follow the second plot.

Comment: My original Code is much longer and with multiple functions. I dont use the command  `Show` in it. So if i add `/. Line->Arrow` all functions get an arrow. Is there a possibilty to use `/. Line->Arrow` seperatly on functions?

Comment: @ManuelFülling, please see update 2.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using `NSolve` to find the intersection point and `Graphics` to draw the arrows:

```
func[x_, b_] := b*x;
Manipulate[
 With[{xIntersection = 
    NSolve[{a*Sin[x] == func[x, b], x > 0}, x, Reals][[1, 1, 2]]},
  Show[
   Plot[{a*Sin[x], func[x, b]},
    {x, 0, 2 Pi},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-6, 6}}
    ],
   Graphics[{
     Point@{xIntersection, func[xIntersection, b]},
     Arrowheads@0.03,
     Red, Arrow@{{0, 0}, {xIntersection, 0}},
     Blue, Arrow@{{2 Pi, 0}, {xIntersection, 0}}
     }]
   ]
  ],
 {a, 1, 10}, {b, 0.5, 10}
 ]
```

[image]